# How to define sentence complexity?

Tags: syntax, semantics, computational-linguistics, theoretical-linguistics, complexity

I am not a pure linguist but rather at the intersection of computational linguistics, NLP and computer science. Thus please be cautious with me and my ignorance. I am looking for definitions of sentence complexity - possibly with respect to information / entropy. For example, a matrix sentence like `The washing machine which is on top of the shelf is running` is clearly more complex than `The washing machine is running`. So one naive way of defining one sentence is more complex than another would be counting how many sentences are recursively incorporated. Another way would be counting the length of the sentence. My question would be, is there any formal work on defining this more thoroughly? I would very much appreciate any hints!

---

I found these things so far, writing this to make sure references don't repeat and for own documentation purpose:

**StackExchange questions:**

[Measuring semantic complexity of a text](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13006/measuring-semantic-complexity-of-a-text?rq=1)

[Measuring syntactic complexity](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/measuring-syntactic-complexity)

**Semantics:**

[Semantic entropy](https://aclanthology.org/W97-0207.pdf)

[Lexical Density](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZvEbAQAAIAAJ&hl=de&source=gbs_book_other_versions) (Chapt. 5 and 6)

**Syntax:**

[Dependency distance as a metric of language comprehension difficulty](http://www.lingviko.net/JCS.pdf)

[Syntacic Complexity](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/273276/1-s2.0-S0019995874X0058X/1-s2.0-S0019995874800586/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECkaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGTg7usnWdqCYL06%2F%2FQYreEP9Th3pGmSSFGVTXipCY%2BvAiAHx%2BXWCLwlQxgH%2Bb2gjWCSL4TBcZZQovc%2BtrcWjO6o9CqDBAjB%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMNC5lbAhEPCuC8DwpKtcDiW65nWNuqkfHA2JhvZM10vJ3fmh%2Buq90zhvg9S9XU7uW6BpIiwPhJonHcUMEDhNxWWMtdeNhqVgERPddD5MZKUwvIcEoK2%2FU5WgRJOpu35wnEvRg9XvM%2BfHfcCBigSGLZhc4F1NaIru2KTzi8pggVt68A3DljlHJd5bVJrP95XXC6Y36PwCSkrYJ%2FZAXZK3Ooang2SPBr1daJsj6Z5uhvAwlVPzL8QhXXbf03nyxoCGF%2FytcNiKjxlWmRjbURnazescdOP8UD8iSGA2dQ6PUBLEHMVCQgigG9WAtmVqH7Vs7FNyFoUPN3RmeIj%2FJ1n%2FDXsPKnxITFz2qymSXYxRRAh7wDN6Q3Xhvq1X8MhfLrzXIN1QiT%2BgqXRaGgbFSM1EPPSD6yFqQ%2Bdxm9qOLfv9YLweth5P%2F9SG0l8faDPkMJ0OPd1n8iE%2BeKVuzdGSvNNSkdmFQ0v8Lag0z8bykvoKegsW%2B2hUjFY0QX6xZI%2BEti5%2B2GY95E6jwpxNxXtWGvkf9w2eC8zAVwoZyrhF8QGj3qH5gvfJK5z2FGVQ9E5iR9VydTklCsVmoBbbjswMfiZnSl0nAwlnrCSvdEeV0lb4iMtUrR0X7p16itV8kaZjaUNcVvE6pEi0vMPq58IsGOqYBRGTWwX%2Fr8p19JHoJc5PH42oM%2B2GjvENSL%2FRhh6FuHaTElPAK7zohsS9TH5PzaLp1aNIFC3EoFhlnbzxxo4CiiTFKka%2FqDRC7S9PpfnnSidKrIvhLnFs5YklSsqRlOni%2BfMgIBjTiJrUUPRlyuCrYIuObuRq8VyuB9ezWFR3mtSW3BVPHgbNneZRtUyNEAd6cq8G0g2241NddWAOBP0H3goOGTAyimA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211029T170708Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUDRNSOIS%2F20211029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=93c2825ff684dd18319e1e05ca50fc6d0d0da12ad8150834b4d712da3d9b6de8&hash=c943aefdd876db424dffbaa5ca6e370a937959ad5f1029e74cb52df91bf674d8&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0019995874800586&tid=spdf-93651a4b-87a3-4224-af22-4a7b5048a135&sid=aa7a20963009194e829bc874c3049376bb12gxrqb&type=client)

[Some syntactic determinants of sentential complexity](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2FBF03211044.pdf)

[Some syntactic determinants of sentential
complexity, II: Verb structure](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03205754.pdf)

[On Operationalizing Syntactic Complexity](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ebresnan/LabSyntax/szmrecsanyi-syntactic.complexity.pdf)

**Morphology:**

[Measuring syntactic complexity](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/measuring-syntactic-complexity) (here, curiousdannii suggests to look at morphology. I haven't seen anything on it. I wonder if morphology is relevant considering I am only looking at English.)

**Misc:**

[Curriculum learning for language modelling](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02170) (Sec. 3)

[Readability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability)

[A model for language structure](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4453/RLE-TR-369-06411244.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Some time ago I used Laurence Sterne's novel _The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman_ to test the level of my own adequacy before going to audiences with the headmaster of the school where I worked — the sentences in the novel are often a paragraph long and are so paradoxical and mind-twisting that understanding some was a real challenge. On the other hand, Michael Moorcock in his novels could have a page-long sentence enumerating in a list the types of planes that were simultaneously bombing Berlin during WWIII. Two kinds of sentence complexity, which one do you prefer?

Comment: I suggest checking out the concept of and work on _dependency distance_ as it is understood in _dependency grammar_ (DG). Dependency distance is calculated by counting the number of words separating a given word from its head word. One calculates the dependency distance for each word in a sentence and then arrives at an average. The greater this number, the greater the syntactic complexity and thus the more difficult the sentence is to process. Do a google search for _dependency grammar dependency distance_. DG is of course quite prominent in NLP circles.

Comment: @YellowSky: I am not sure. The first one seems more complicated to me, though concepts are related sequentially. But we have a weird jump back to the first concept (the novel) in the end of the sentence. The second seems more readable. The thing is. It doesn't really matter, which _I_ like, because I am looking for sentences which a machine considers as complex - and that is _very_ intransparent if we consider machine learning models. So my take here is to look at various concepts and do trial-and-error.

Comment: @TimOsborne: thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look!

Answer (score 4):

There are early works on the topic in [Some syntactic determinants of sentential complexity](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2FBF03211044.pdf) and [Some syntactic determinants of sentential complexity, II: Verb structure](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03205754.pdf). These focus on "perceptual complexity". [This](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ebresnan/LabSyntax/szmrecsanyi-syntactic.complexity.pdf) much later paper (and references therein) has a very different approach but seems to equate "complexity" with "psychological difficulty". [This 1974 paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0019995874800586?token=63D93E43793A5E6A372F118AB3F2217E8EC902AB49DFE26835B7D1E939FC425A18E721B3190786AA7C73A3787DA27CE3&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20211027213756) on the other hand takes a mathematical linguistic stance, and aims to compute complexity, but I can't discern an actual *definition* of complexity. Complexity enters into the discussion of [this classic 1959 paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4453/RLE-TR-369-06411244.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), which measures complexity in terms of depth of postponed symbols, but also takes for granted what complexity is. All told, it seems that people in the field equate psychological difficulty with "complexity". "Complexity" is generally not a consideration in generative syntactic theories, so definitions most likely will come from another discipline.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look at all of these!

Comment: So it is more of a semantic and cognitive question?

Comment: Since syntax is more of a personal matter, abstract "complexity" will vary wildly depending more on individual factors than structural ones. What's simple for you may be complex for me, and vice versa.

Comment: @jlawler: but there must be a universal notion, no? Assuming we are both as literate and have the same knowledge. Or even if we assumed we didn't, then some sentences are harder than others, and however we order this likely coincides. At some point of the scale for someone illerate distinguishing a super complex and a pretty complex sentence might be hard, but I am somehow presuming an ordering with respect to some concept must be possible.

Comment: My structural definition of "complexity" is purely a count of nodes and relations. Usually people equate complexity with difficulty, which raises the question "difficulty in doing what?". You seems to equate "complexity" with "hardness" (I don't): so no, there is no universal definition. I urge you to get rid of "complexity" and focus on what seems to be most important for you, namely "difficulty in doing ___" (producing? understanding? reading? pronouncing? remembering?).

Comment: I really appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 2):

In the CAF-framework (Complexity, Accuracy, Fluency) used in language teaching syntactic complexity is measured in terms of words per unit, where the unit can be the complete sentence, a clause, or a T-unit. The measure is very practical and applicable, and it seems that other measures don't add much to that.

See also [this question on languagelearning.se](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2719/172)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at the framework!